# Overriding an equals method from the java...Object class

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

I've been attempting to figure out the rationale behind this question and I have been struggling to see why the outcome is what it is. I will explain everything I understand and I hope someone will be able to fill in the blanks for me.

Imagine you have a class:

```
public class Point {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || (!(o instanceof Point)) { // Let's call this method 1
            return false;
        }
        Point other = (Point) o;
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Point p) { // Let's call this method 2
        if (p == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return x == p.x && y == p.y;
    }
}
```

Now we create the following objects:

```
Object o = new Object()

Point p = new Point(3,4)

Object op = new Point(3,4)
```

If we call:

```
p.equals(o) // this calls method 1

p.equals(p) // this calls method 2

p.equals(op) // this calls method 1
```

However, this is where I get confused.

```
op.equals(o) // this calls method 1

op.equals(op) // this calls method 1

op.equals(p) // this calls method 1
```

Why does the last one call method 1? Shouldn't the method signature of method 2 warrant the call to go there?

If anyone could explain it to me that would be great!

Comment: You can't override the signature of `Object.equals(Object)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`op` is a variable of type `Object`, which has no method having the signature `public boolean equals(Point p)`. Hence the only `equals` method that can be executed by calling `op.equals()` (regardless of the argument type) has the signature `boolean equals (Object o)`. Your `Point` class overrides `boolean equals (Object o)`, so your method 1 is called in all of the latter 3 cases.

Answer (score 1):

Given that

```
Point p = new Point(3,4)
Object op = new Point(3,4)
```

and since `op` is an `Object`

```
op.equals(p)
```

will call the `equals(Object o)` method, because that's the only `equals` method that `Object` has.